# Synonyms for “you’ve got a point”

Tags: synonyms

What is another way of saying “you make a good point!” / “you’ve got some good points”?

I am struggling to think of an alternative way to say it. The word ‘point’ is an homophone and isn’t translating well into another language.

Comment: "Well done!" "Indeed!" "You're right about that!" "I agree with you!" "You are very wise!" "Touché!" "Well duh!" "That's as maybe!" and thousands more. Can you be a bit more precise about what you want? Are you agreeing with the person, or conceding that one of their thousands of opinions are correct while all the rest are wrong?

Comment: So the other language ought to have a way to express the “you’ve got a point” concept.  What that is is a question for that other language’s stack exchange.

Comment: @StuartF I’m trying to distinguish between “you have a good idea” and “you make a good point”. I think the two have slightly nuanced differences. To me the latter indicates that a change of perception has occurred in the speaker, whereas the former does not.

Comment: I'd just say "ok, fair enough" then move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in:

> You make a good point!

My friend thought of a way to still convey the change of perception in the speaker:

> On second thoughts, you’re right!

I’ve also since seen an unrelated trending question and thought of:

> As a matter of fact, you’re right!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest and most useful strategy is not just the compliment -
start by saying something like "I hear you saying" and then use
your own words and end by saying "I suspect you're right; I'm gonna
think about it" or some such. That satisfies them if you're right
and gives them a chance to correct you if you're wrong.

Of course it might start an argument, too. Not everyone can be right.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that changes with the context of the situation.

If you're looking for synonyms for "point," then I'd suggest the following:

- Idea(s)
- Suggestion(s)
- Solution(s)
- Argument(s)

These are all acceptable ways to say "what the person has thought of and shared with you."

Answer (score 1):

You could also say

> What you say (actually) makes sense!

or

> I see what you mean and I tend to agree with you.

or

> M, quite right. Haven't thought of that before.

Answer (score 1):

During a discussion, one can say *Granted* as an alternative to "You've got a point." It means that you grant this item of the discussion.

For example,

> Person A: This law has never been enforced.
>
> Person B: Granted. But do you think it should have been rescinded?

Please see definition 3b of *grant* (v).

> b: to assume to be true. *granting that you are correct*

[Source, M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grant).